# Register virtual class with UVM factory

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Does anyone have a way of registering virtual classes with the factory? Using the object_utils macro will define the type_id::create(...) method which calls new(...) for the virtual class which is illegal.

Naturally, a type override would be mandatory for any virtual class registered with the factory. It would be cool if anyone had an elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in the UVM with a virtual class without recreating your own factory. However, you could instrument the build_phase() of this class to check that the class has been overridden. Either way you would not be able to check this until run time. So you lose the compiler check that a virtual class provides, so why bother using it.

Comment: I've played around some more with this and have got it working, but by using the internal macros that uvm_object_utils calls. This is surely bad practice, but here's the code for anyone who is more adventurous: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3iJ

Comment: Since you're involved in UVM development, maybe you can consider this as a feature? @dave

Comment: I explain the code behind the factory in detail in my new [SystemVerilog OOP for UVM Verification](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification) course.